# php smarty really need help

Tags: php, sql, session, smarty

Hey guys I have no idea why this wont work...It doesn't seem to want to pick up the POST values....I can't figure it out

This is loginbox

```
<div class="loginbox">
<form action="processlogin.php" method="post">

    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>Username</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="UserName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><span style="font-size:12px;"><a href="adduser.php">Click here to register</a></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is just a box I embed into my index template.

```
  <div class="header">
    {if loggedin == false}
        <h1>welcome</h1>
    {else}
        {include file="loginbox.tpl"}
    {/if}
  </div>
```

Loginbox when submited goes to processlogin.php which is this

```
<?php
include '/usr/local/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
require "includes/defs.php";
$smarty = new Smarty;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    // Get any error message
    $error = @$_GET['error'];
    } else 
    {

        $UserName = @$_POST['UserName'];
        $Password = @$_POST['Password'];
        echo $UserName;
    }
processlogin($UserName, $Password);

?>
```

This calls the function processlogin...but even before that I was testing to see if I could even get UserName and I can't...

```
    function processlogin($UserName, $Password){
    echo $UserName;
session_start();
$UserName = mysql_escape_string($UserName);
$Password = md5($Password);
echo $UserName;

    $connection = mysql_open();
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE UserName = '$UserName' AND UserPass = '$Password'";

    $Result = @ mysql_query($SQL)
     or showerror();

    if(mysql_num_rows($Result) > 0)
    {
        $DATA = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result);
        $_SESSION['userID'] = $DATA['ID'];
        $_SESSION['Loggedin'] = "true"; 
        echo 'true';
        //header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['Loggedin'] = "false";
        echo 'trdddde';
        //header("Location:index.php");
    }

}
```

This is the function...you will see I just have random tests in which make no real sense. I am just trying to make it show things along the way so I can figure out what's going wrong

Sorry for my poor coding skills. I've only been learning for 2 or so months now.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of what you've posted, you're stopping your session from being started properly by echoing debug info:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    // Get any error message
    $error = @$_GET['error'];
} else {

    $UserName = @$_POST['UserName'];
    $Password = @$_POST['Password'];
    echo $UserName;
}
processlogin($UserName, $Password);
```

The call to `session_start` is in the `processlogin` function, which comes after you've already output content to the browser.  This is what the PHP maunal says:

> To use cookie-based sessions,
>   session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser.

Try removing the line `echo $UserName;`

HTH.

p.s.  Seeing as you're a beginner, note that your `processlogin` function is susceptible to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Actually, the bit about the SQL injection attacks is wrong - sorry!

Comment: It still is not working. I think it has issues somewhere getting the variables from the form. Because even before the process login is run it should show the echo of UserName...I remove the error checking and the echo it still does not work.

What appears is "traddde" which is my way of saying if loggedin == false.

Comment: I fixed it...but I have NO idea how...it just started working...I changed nothing and suddenly it worked.